# GUI Only By Using FPC

Tags: user-interface, pascal, lazarus, freepascal, fpc

I want to know how I can develop GUI applications(32 Bits) without using Delphi language(Object Pascsl), only by using FPC with Lazarus installed(Pascal). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a widget set directly. Look at e.g. the examples in packages/gtk2 for unix, or the windows win32api usage demo. (demo\win32 in the FPC win32 installation)

But not using lazarus makes you lose platform independance, and a lot of ease.

Looking how lazarus does it, is still a possibility.

A second option is https://github.com/mse-org/mseide-msegui

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [FPC Qt4 Binding](http://users.telenet.be/Jan.Van.hijfte/qtforfpc/fpcqt4.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at built in [LCL](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/LCL_Components), and external [fpGUI](http://opensoft.homeip.net:8080/fpgui) and [mseGUI](http://wiki.freepascal.org/MSEide_&_MSEgui).